# Make column hidden in handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have the below code for handsontable. Unfortunately, i could not find any documentation if i want to keep 1 column hidden on my browser but i need it to be there because of my server side processing limitation.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    columnSorting: true,
    stretchH: "all",    
    className: "htCenter",
    colHeaders: ['Country', 'Post Location', 'Code', 'Distribution Center', 'Post Location Id'],
    data: data,
    columns: [
    {
        data: 'country_name',
        editor : false
    },
    {
        data: 'label',
        editor : false
    },
    {
        data: 'code',
        editor : false
    },
    {
        data: 'channel_name',
        type: 'dropdown',
        source: distribution_centers
    },
    {
        data: 'post_location_id',
        editor: false,

    }
    ]
});
```

Is there any way that i can set my `post_location_id` column hidden ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remove it from your columns definition. It will still be in the `data` array but it just won't get rendered.

Comment: No it is not in `data` array if i remove it from my column definition.

Comment: It should be. Could you update your code to include the format of `data` and how you generate it? Handsontable will only generate a reference back to this array, not create a new one. So if you have other information on each row object it will be available whether you add it to `columns` or not.